# How can I make the Unity2d grid use rounded numbers?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I am creating a simple grid-based game to understand things better. In the game I have a "start position" tile that sets where my hero will start the level. However, I can not seem to get the tile to be located at a clean (1,2) kind of coordinate. Instead, the location of the tile is always a long float out to several decimal places, like (-3.897622, 0.9561565).

This is creating problems further down the road when I want to specific particular cell/tile locations.

Is there a way to force unity to use Ints or rounded floats for its grid locations?

Comment: You can turn on SNAP, however it doesnt stop you manually putting things in places

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. You're more likely to get a response if you detail what research you took to try to find a solution.  Please see the Stack Overflow Question Guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you add some code of where your placing is happening? Unity itself doesn't just place your objects to random positions but where you tell it to ...